# Can't solve problem with response.body().string()

Tags: android, httpresponse

I am trying to send stringCentroid to other activity class but the log says it is null string.

```
public class Centroid extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = "result";
    TextView centroid;
    String stringUrl =".net/MeetingLocationCentroid?location=";
    String data = "{";
    private GeoApiContext mGeoApiContext = null;
    private GoogleMap map;
    String stringCentroid = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.centroid_result);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


        centroid = findViewById(R.id.centroid);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ArrayList<AddressItem> addresses = (ArrayList<AddressItem>) intent.getSerializableExtra("locations");
        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
            data += addresses.get(i).latlng;
            if (i!=addresses.size()-1)
                data += ",";
        }
        stringUrl = stringUrl  + data+"}";
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(stringUrl)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    Centroid.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "myResponse: "+myResponse);

                            stringCentroid += myResponse;
                            centroid.setText(stringCentroid);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "centroid textview = "+centroid.getText().toString());

        Log.d(TAG, "stringCentroid: "+stringCentroid);
        //Intent pushIntent = new Intent(Centroid.this, MainActivity.class);
        //pushIntent.putExtra("centroid",stringCentroid);
        //startActivity(pushIntent);
    }

}
```

this is my code. And below is my log

```
/result: stringCentroid:
/result: centroid textview = 
/result: myResponse: [37.440605, 126.892082]
```

the log shows that myResponse is String but others are not. What is wrong? How can I give string to stringCentroid? Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Your Log prints right after you call the request. the values would only be updated after the network call is finished. Try putting your `Log.d` inside your `run()` method after getting the values

Comment: It works with the log. So does that mean I have send intent within the network call?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Logging the Variables immediately after Starting the request. Put you Logging codes and your `startActivity` inside the run function like this:

```
public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "myResponse: "+myResponse);
    stringCentroid += myResponse;
    centroid.setText(stringCentroid);

    Log.d(TAG, "centroid textview = "+centroid.getText().toString());

    Log.d(TAG, "stringCentroid: "+stringCentroid);
    Intent pushIntent = new Intent(Centroid.this, MainActivity.class);
    pushIntent.putExtra("centroid",stringCentroid);
    startActivity(pushIntent);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when i try to get intent in the main activity with this line String centroid = intent.getExtras().getString("centroid"); problem occurs saying centroid is null. What might be wrong?

Comment: not sure, could be that your "centroid" key may be spelt differently in both activities. Can't say without seeing the MainActivity code

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code inside runOnUIThread -> run() function because it runs on thread and it can be executed after startActivity function.

```
Log.d(TAG, "centroid textview = "+centroid.getText().toString());
Log.d(TAG, "stringCentroid: "+stringCentroid);
Intent pushIntent = new Intent(Centroid.this, MainActivity.class);
pushIntent.putExtra("centroid",stringCentroid);
startActivity(pushIntent);
```